# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rolling'

Tags: python, pandas

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mov_avg.py", line 9, in <module>
    data_frame['100ma']= data_frame['Adj Close'].rolling(window=100, min_periods=0).mean()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2360, in __getattr__
    (type(self).__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'rolling'
```

Comment: What is your Pandas version? `rolling` was added in Pandas 0.18.0

Answer (score 9):

Most probably you are using old Pandas version (< 0.18.0).

[Series.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) has been added in Pandas 0.18.0

Comment: What was used before that?